# Need to add some conditions before service get called RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, primeng

I am new to Angular and I am using primeng Datatable to show a grid in my application, now I have integrated pagination for the grid as well, I need to an add loading / spinner symbol to the grid when the user searches or clicks on page number.
 Below, serviceloading is set to true at the start of method but service wasn't called at a particular instance which makes to show loading always, actually I do hide the loading only when I get the response. So is there any way where I can set loading to true at the start of API call so that I could hide after I get response.

Thanks in Advance

```
private TransactionSearch: Subject<void> = new Subject();
loadTerritories(event:LazyLoadEvent)
{
    this.serviceloading = true;
    this.params = event.filters.TerritoryName;
    this.TransactionSearch.next();     
    this.TransactionSearch.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(1000),
      switchMap(() => { 
            return this.TransService.getSalesTerritory(this.params);
      })).
      subscribe(res =>{ 
        this.totalcount = res.Total; 
        this.salesTerritoryList =  res.Data;  
        this.serviceloading = false;     
      });
  }
```

HTML Content

```
<p-table 
   #dt 
   [value]="salesTerritoryList" 
   [autoLayout]="true" 
   [totalRecords]="totalcount"
   [paginator]="true" 
   [rows]="15" 
   [lazy]="true"
   [loading]="serviceloading"
   (onLazyLoad)="loadSalesTerritories($event)"
>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to add tap to your pipe below the switchMap.  Please see below.  I hope this helps.

```
this.TransactionSearch.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  debounceTime(1000),
  tap(() => { 
    this.serviceloading = true;
  }),
  switchMap(() => { return this.TransService.getSalesTerritory(this.params);})).
  subscribe(res =>{ 
    this.totalcount = res.Total; 
    this.salesTerritoryList =  res.Data;  
    this.serviceloading = false;     
  });
```

Comment: Awesome, can you mark the answer as correct for future users by upvoting it.

Comment: I couldn't upvote. "Thanks for your feedback. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"